# Monitor icecast using node.js

Tags: node.js, icecast

I've got a rather vague question, but I'm hoping for some help.

I have icecast installed on an unbuntu server, with two server blocks setup using nginx.

Icecast is set to stream on https://stream.domain.com:8443/stream

I have a node.js app running on https://app.domain.com

Is there a way to "listen" to the icecast domain/stream/port using node and start a function when the stream starts, and stop it when the stream stops?

I'm not hoping for a full solution, just clues to point me in the right direction! Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can set this up within your icecast config using the `<on-connect>` and `<on-disconnect>` tags

Answer (score 0):

Make a request to

```
https://stream.domain.com:8443/status-json.xsl
```

it will return a JSON status of the server, then see the "source" key in this JSON - not empty "source" will indicate that there is a source connected to the server and Icecast is broadcasting something.
That JSON also provides a lot of additional info you can also use.

Also a basic check is to try to connect to port 8443 - if connection is not happening in, say, 5 seconds - that will indicate that Icecast is completely down.

Comment: I'm aware of the status-json.xsl, but the problem is that my node app is running on the server, and it should do something when the icecast stream goes live. I can not manually request the status url.

Comment: Why not request Icecast JSON by interval, say 5 seconds? And react when it is online.